# Website with Azure Mobile Backend

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i'm currently making an app with xamarin forms with an azure backend, one of the features of my app is to be able to upload long videos to azure blob storage, however since most of these videos will be big files and be edited on a computer I figure it's better to be able to upload the video file via a computer using a website, however is it possible to connect a website to the same azure mobile backend that my app is using, and if so how would I do that, if not any other good alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are familiar with Asp.Net WebApi 2, OData V3, MVC4+, EF6 and hosting with IIS. If so, then simply build the self-hosting WebApi Project and write a web api controller to upload the file using Async and Stream and host the project in Azure. You can upload the file either using computer ( there should be backend dashboard which you can build in MVC4 and use same web api controller) or mobile app if needed.

For sample of how to build Web Api check out this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v3/creating-an-odata-endpoint) and Post controller

```
public async Task<List<string>> PostAsync()
{
    if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        string uploadPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/uploads");

        MyStreamProvider streamProvider = new MyStreamProvider(uploadPath);

        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);

        List<string> messages = new List<string>();
        foreach(var file in streamProvider.FileData)
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file.LocalFileName);
            messages.Add("File uploaded as " + fi.FullName + " (" + fi.Length + " bytes)");
        }

        return messages;
    }
    else
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid Request!");
        throw new HttpResponseException(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I create an asp web app I can conect it to my mobile backend and it should work fine alongside the mobile app?

Comment: Yes  it works. You can consume Webservice and implement Post method to upload video file and rest of your functionality will be as it is.

Comment: so just connect the asp.net app to the backend just like I did with my mobile app